# What is Semantical Memory Leak?

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, storage, heap-memory, definition

I understand the definition of a **Memory Leak** but couldn't find anything referred to **Semantical** or **Semantic Memory Leak** and the differences to [memory leak](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Memory_leak).

Example for a *memory leak*:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void function_which_allocates(void) {
    /* allocate an array of 45 floats */
    float *a = malloc(sizeof(float) * 45);

    /* additional code making use of 'a' */

    /* return to main, having forgotten to free the memory we malloc'd */
}
int main(void) {
    function_which_allocates();

    /* the pointer 'a' no longer exists, and therefore cannot be freed,
     but the memory is still allocated. a leak has occurred. */
}
```

Comment: Where did you find semantical memory leak? any references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definition** *(Semantical garbage)*

A variable which the program will never use again, but
still keeps a reference to it, is called semantic garbage.

```
class Huge {
    Huge() { // Constructor:
             // Allocates lots of data and stores
             // it in the newly created object
    }
}

void f() {
    Huge semanticGarbage = new Huge();
    heavy.computation(new Indeed(100));
    System.exit(1);
}
```

All sophisticated GC algorithms contend in vain against semantic garbage.

> *Reference:*
>   **Technion CS 234319: Programming Languages Course**
>
> (Lecture) **Chapter 5** Storage  *5.5* Automatic memory management - Semantical memory leak

Answer (score 0):

Definition (Semantical garbage)
A variable which the program will never use again, but
still keeps a reference to it, is called semantic garbage.

In other words, imagine allocating an array in your main program and using it only in the first few lines, and after you're done not freeing it. basically the major difference between a semantic memory leak and a memory leak is that, in a memory leak you have no reference to the unfreed array, however in a semantic leak you actually have a reference to it although you're no longer using it.